# How to solve integral on complex circle?

Tags: integration

I found in a book that

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}  \int_\Gamma \frac{x^{-n-1}}{x_0 - x}dx = a(n) x_o^{-n-1}$$

where $a(n) =1 $ for $n \geq 0 $ and $a(n)=0$ for $n < 0$ and $\Gamma$ is a positively-oriented small circle in $\mathbb{C}$ enclosing $0$ and $x_0$ is a point outside the circle.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? I found it in the book *Perturabtion Theory for Linear Operators* from Kato on page 38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n < 0$, the integrand is analytic inside and on $\Gamma$, which by Cauchy's theorem, implies that the integral is zero. If $n \ge 0$, then your integral is of the form $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}}\, dx$$ where $f(x) := \frac{1}{x_0 - x}$ is analytic inside and on $\Gamma$. So by Cauchy's differentiation formula, the value of the integral is $$\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{1}{n!}[n!(x_0 - x)^{-n-1}]\bigg|_{x = 0} = x_0^{-n-1}.$$

Comment: Wow! Funny that the author does not even make a not on that. Thank you.